# cakephp4 ：Unable to save association in hasone

Tags: php, cakephp

I wrote the following code to store data from MailFormsController to the Customers and Messages models

**Controllers/MailFormsController.php**

```
        <?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Controller;
use Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager;
use Cake\Core\Exception\Exception;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
/**
 * MailForms Controller
 *
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\MailForm[]|\Cake\Datasource\ResultSetInterface paginate($object = null, array $settings = [])
 */
class MailFormsController extends AppController
{
    /**
     * Index method
     *
     * @return \Cake\Http\Response|null|void Renders view
     */
    public function index()
    {
        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
            // $this->loadModel('Customers');
            $this->Customers = TableRegistry::get('customers');
            $this->Messages = TableRegistry::get('messages');
            $post_data = $this->request->getData();

            $customerData = $this->Customers->newEmptyEntity();
            $customerData = $this->Customers->patchEntity($customerData, $this->request->getData(), ['associated' => ['Messages']]);

            if ($this->Customers->save($customerData)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The site name has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error(__('The entry data could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**view template templates/MailForms/index.php**

```
<?php

echo $this->Form->create();
echo $this->Form->control('name');
echo $this->Form->control('mail');
echo $this->Form->control('messages.0.message_1');
echo $this->Form->control('messages.0.message_2');
echo $this->Form->control('messages.0.message_3');
echo $this->Form->button('POST', ['type' => 'submit']);
```

**Model/Table/CustomersTable.php**

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App/Model/Table;

    use Cake\ORM\Query;
    use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
    use Cake\ORM\Table;
    use Cake\Validation\Validator;
    
    /**
     * Customers Model
     *
     * @method \App\Model\Entity\Customer newEmptyEntity()
     * @method \App\Model\Entity\Customer newEntity(array $data, array $options = [])
     * @method \App\Model\Entity\Customer[] newEntities(array $data, array $options = [])
     * @method \App\Model\Entity\Customer get($primaryKey, $options = [])
     * @method \App\Model\Entity\Customer findOrCreate($search, ?callable $callback = null, $options = [])
     * @method \App\Model\Entity\Customer patchEntity(\Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface $entity, array $data, array $options = [])
     * @method \App\Model\Entity\Customer[] patchEntities(iterable $entities, array $data, array $options = [])
     * @method \App\Model\Entity\Customer|false save(\Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface $entity, $options = [])
     * @method \App\Model\Entity\Customer saveOrFail(\Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface $entity, $options = [])
     * @method \App\Model\Entity\Customer[]|\Cake\Datasource\ResultSetInterface|false saveMany(iterable $entities, $options = [])
     * @method \App\Model\Entity\Customer[]|\Cake\Datasource\ResultSetInterface saveManyOrFail(iterable $entities, $options = [])
     * @method \App\Model\Entity\Customer[]|\Cake\Datasource\ResultSetInterface|false deleteMany(iterable $entities, $options = [])
     * @method \App\Model\Entity\Customer[]|\Cake\Datasource\ResultSetInterface deleteManyOrFail(iterable $entities, $options = [])
     *
     * @mixin \Cake\ORM\Behavior\TimestampBehavior
     */
    class CustomersTable extends Table
    {
        /**
         * Initialize method
         *
         * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
         * @return void
         */
        public function initialize(array $config): void
        {
            parent::initialize($config);
    
            $this->setTable('customers');
            $this->setDisplayField('name');
            $this->setPrimaryKey('id');
            $this->hasOne('Messages')->setForeignKey('customers_id');
            $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
    
        }
    
        /**
         * Default validation rules.
         *
         * @param \Cake\Validation\Validator $validator Validator instance.
         * @return \Cake\Validation\Validator
         */
        public function validationDefault(Validator $validator): Validator
        {
            $validator
                ->scalar('name')
                ->maxLength('name', 255)
                ->requirePresence('name', 'create')
                ->notEmptyString('name');
    
            $validator
                ->scalar('mail')
                ->maxLength('mail', 255)
                ->requirePresence('mail', 'create')
                ->notEmptyString('mail');
    
            return $validator;
        }
    }
```

**Model/Table/MessagesTable.php**

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Query;
use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

/**
 * Messages Model
 *
 * @property \App\Model\Table\CustomersTable&\Cake\ORM\Association\BelongsTo $Customers
 *
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\Message newEmptyEntity()
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\Message newEntity(array $data, array $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\Message[] newEntities(array $data, array $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\Message get($primaryKey, $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\Message findOrCreate($search, ?callable $callback = null, $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\Message patchEntity(\Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface $entity, array $data, array $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\Message[] patchEntities(iterable $entities, array $data, array $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\Message|false save(\Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface $entity, $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\Message saveOrFail(\Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface $entity, $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\Message[]|\Cake\Datasource\ResultSetInterface|false saveMany(iterable $entities, $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\Message[]|\Cake\Datasource\ResultSetInterface saveManyOrFail(iterable $entities, $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\Message[]|\Cake\Datasource\ResultSetInterface|false deleteMany(iterable $entities, $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\Message[]|\Cake\Datasource\ResultSetInterface deleteManyOrFail(iterable $entities, $options = [])
 *
 * @mixin \Cake\ORM\Behavior\TimestampBehavior
 */
class MessagesTable extends Table
{
    /**
     * Initialize method
     *
     * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
     * @return void
     */
    public function initialize(array $config): void
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('messages');
        $this->setDisplayField('id');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        $this->belongsTo('Customers', [
            'foreignKey' => 'customers_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Default validation rules.
     *
     * @param \Cake\Validation\Validator $validator Validator instance.
     * @return \Cake\Validation\Validator
     */
    public function validationDefault(Validator $validator): Validator
    {
        $validator
            ->integer('customers_id')
            ->requirePresence('customers_id', 'create')
            ->notEmptyString('customers_id');

        $validator
            ->scalar('message_1')
            ->maxLength('message_1', 255)
            ->requirePresence('message_1', 'create')
            ->notEmptyString('message_1');

        $validator
            ->scalar('message_2')
            ->maxLength('message_2', 255)
            ->requirePresence('message_2', 'create')
            ->notEmptyString('message_2');

        $validator
            ->scalar('message_3')
            ->requirePresence('message_3', 'create')
            ->notEmptyString('message_3');

        return $validator;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a rules checker object that will be used for validating
     * application integrity.
     *
     * @param \Cake\ORM\RulesChecker $rules The rules object to be modified.
     * @return \Cake\ORM\RulesChecker
     */
    public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules): RulesChecker
    {
        $rules->add($rules->existsIn('customers_id', 'Customers'), ['errorField' => 'customers_id']);

        return $rules;
    }
}
```

I have set up an association in CustomersTable.php with hasone for Messages, but when I run this program, the data is only stored in the Customers table and not in the Messages table.

Please tell me what is wrong with this program and how do I get the associations saved?

Answer (score 0):

Because it's a `hasOne` relationship, there will be only one message per customer, and your fields should be named accordingly:

```
echo $this->Form->control('message.message_1');
echo $this->Form->control('message.message_2');
echo $this->Form->control('message.message_3');
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I modified the source code as you suggested, but the data is still stored only in the customers table and not in the messages table.
Is there anything else I need to fix?

Comment: @usuif Your entities need to make the fields [**accessible**](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/entities.html#entities-mass-assignment), you should pass the customer entity to [**`FormHelper::create()`**](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/views/helpers/form.html#starting-a-form), and you should close your form with [**`FormHelper::end()`**](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/views/helpers/form.html#closing-the-form).

Comment: @usuif Also never use superglobals like `$_SERVER` directly with CakePHP, but the abstract [**request API**](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/controllers/request-response.html#checking-request-conditions) (`$this->request->is(['post', 'patch'])`). Furthermore debug your customer entity (`debug($customerData);`) after patching as well as after saving to see if there's missing data, errors, etc.

Comment: @ndm Thanks for the reply.
I am using $this->request->getData(); is this a bad idea?
Also, how should I code FormHelper::create() to adapt the customer entity?